# Is the discontinuation of the petitioning system "We the People" constitutional?

Tags: united-states, constitution, petition

On January 20, 2021, the day of the Inauguration of Joe Biden, the website of We the People petitioning system https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/about started redirecting to the main whitehouse.gov domain. This was first reported by the Ron Paul Institute, the White House declined comment when a reporter from Newsweek asked about the apparent discontinuation of the website. It has not been relaunched since. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_the_People_(petitioning_system)))

I wonder if the discontinuation of the petitioning system "We the People" goes against the U.S. constitution.

The First Amendment (Amendment I) to the United States Constitution prevents the government from making laws which regulate an establishment of religion, or that would prohibit the free exercise of religion, or abridge the freedom of speech, the freedom of the press, the freedom of assembly, or the right to petition the government for redress of grievances. It was adopted on December 15, 1791, as one of the ten amendments that constitute the Bill of Rights.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding if there is any argument for it being constitutionally protected or how the constitution has anything related to it. What argument do you present that it is protected or how it would be unconstitutional?

Comment: @DavidS Let me just answer “how the constitution has anything related to it”: this is related to *the right to petition the government for redress of grievances* in the the First Amendment.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the negative reception this question has received is because it can be easily answered with research. The way to avoid this in the future would probably be to either research more first (and include this research in your question, mentioning the parts that you didn't understand, so people have a better understanding of what specifically your problem is)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica what research? I believe have done enough research on this(can you show me some resources on the web?). I previously paste the first amendment here and someone edited and removed it. I was really astonished to see so many people in the free world trying to defend U.S. government for this discontinuation. I will not delete this post, no many how many downvotes I receive.

Comment: @user24711 looking at the first amendment isn't really research, as anybody with the slightest knowledge about the US gov knows about it. Something that would count as research would be looking up interpretations (by Supreme Court justices) of that line in the first amendment, and if they contradict, then asking which one is the viewpoint of the current Supreme Court justices, and if they are all the same viewpoint, well then there's your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The website was merely *one* way of petitioning the government; so your options now are the same as they were before the website was first created - namely, by writing to or e-mailing your representatives directly, arranging to meet with them, organising an actual petition (on paper or on other websites), and the like.

Comment: But in my opinion these methods are way less influential than the We the People system.

Comment: "or **abridge** the freedom of speech, the freedom of the press, the freedom of assembly, or **the right to petition the government for redress of grievances**."  The discontinuation certainly abridged the right.

Comment: @user24711 the discontinuation of the website didn't abridge anyone's rights.  The government has no obligation to provide the most convenient mechanism possible for people to exercise their rights.  A similar line of reasoning would suggest that the government is obligated to provide free computers, blogging software, and hosting to everyone in the US in support of their rights of free speech and freedom of the press, which it clearly isn't.  "In my opinion these methods are way less influential than the We the People system": then perhaps you should petition the government to reinstate it.

Comment: @phoog the discontinuation of the website apparently blocked one of the most convenient ways for people to petition. My question focuses on the discontinuation of an existing system. I am *not* asking whether they are obligated to *build* this website (I also believe they are not ).

Comment: *then perhaps you should petition the government to reinstate it*  That is exactly why I feel like this system is important. "*the White House declined comment when a reporter from Newsweek asked about the apparent discontinuation of the website*" the government can easily ignore any petition of an individual without this system.

Comment: So the question is whether the government, by doing something to make it easier for people to exercise some right, binds itself to continue doing that thing even though it wasn't previously mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

Much of the rights enumerated in the Bill of Rights are understood as negative rights, rather than positive rights. That is, they prohibit the government from doing things that interfere with individuals' actions, rather than require the government to perform acts that aid individuals. The First Amendment falls almost entirely in this category of negative rights. The government is merely prohibited from stopping people from petitioning the government. It isn't required to engage in any affirmative acts to aid the petitioning.

Also, the word "petition" in the First Amendment doesn't refer specifically to a petition in the sense of a document that a bunch of people sign. It just means "Submit requests to the government". Protests, letters to your representatives, speaking at a city council meeting, and lobbying are all petitioning the government.

There have been cases where a mechanism, once established, has been found to require some due process for removing. For instance, when Trump tried to end Obama's DACA program, the courts found that the Administrative Procedure Act required him to follow a particular process to do so, and couldn't just sign an Executive Order. However, they still allowed Trump to remove DACA if he followed the process. Furthermore, I don't think We the People falls under the jurisdiction of the APA or any other similar Act.

Comment: *That is, they prohibit the government from doing things that interfere with individuals' actions, rather than require the government to perform acts that aid individuals*. Okay, but I am asking about the discontinuation part. Isn't the act of discontinuation interfering with individuals' actions, by blocking a way for them to petition?

Comment: I think @phong makes a good point as this is a dangerous ideal he mentions https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71769/is-the-discontinuation-of-the-petitioning-system-we-the-people-constitutional?newreg=d125e904a699461e9268ff63a4631b49#comment295314_71770